# PHP won't run a complicate query, why?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a really strange problem.

This is a part of a .php page:

```
$query="SELECT idlezione, nomemateria, oinizio, ofine FROM materia, lezione, ora, giorno WHERE materia.idmateria=lezione.idmateria AND ora.idora=lezione.idora AND giorno.idgiorno=lezione.giorno AND nomegiorno=\"$nomeg\" AND iddocente=\"$docente\" AND idclasse=\"$classe\" ORDER BY oinizio;";
    echo $query;
    $res=mysql_query($query,$dbconn);
    echo mysql_num_rows($res);
```

Now, when i copy the result of `echo $query;` to phpmyadmin it returns me 2 rows, but in my .php `echo mysql_num_rows($res);` returns "0".

If i use a simple query like `SELECT * FROM materia;` it returns many rows..

UPDATE:
Everything was on altervista.org, now i tried moving my db on local and running the query (using XAMPP) and everyhing works fine.. Why?

Comment: Php can run complicated queries.. give detail about your table shema

Comment: How can my table schema be a problem if the query runs perfectly in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Just as a note: `mysql_` functions have been deprecated for a long time and are removed as of PHP 7 (due later this year). This is because they are unsafe. I highly recommend switching to `mysqli_` or better `PDO` or even better still, an ORM such as Doctrine.

Comment: I know, thanks, but this is not a solution at my problem...

Comment: That's why it's "Just a note" and not an answer. ;) Still looking at the problem.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the query itself which leads me to wonder if the `$dbconn` is connected to the same database as your phpMyAdmin (also don't use phpMyAdmin, that's a security risk too :p)

Comment: any other query in that same file works just fine, so im pretty sure it has nothing to do with $dbconn, just this last one isnt returning any data

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: thanks but that's not the point...

Comment: Add a test after mysql_query: if ($res === FALSE) echo mysql_error($dbconn);

Comment: Try to print mysql_error() after executing the query to be sure there's nothing wrong on it. Anyway, like everybody else, I insist that you should use PDO or mysqli_ because going with deprecated commands is plainly wrong

Comment: I updated the post, is not a problem with mysql functions...

Comment: You might try to execute `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1` on your connection before running your statements

Comment: Maybe its because of the comma on your query: DER BY oinizio**;**. Try removing it

Comment: As far as I know, mysql uses single quotes only too... try changing for example this `nomegiorno=\"$nomeg\"` to `nomegiorno='$nomeg'`

Answer (score -1):

I suggest u use PDO and prepared statements.

Here http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements an introduction to pdo and prepared statements (including bound parameters).